# Where is "an appropriate place" for jar files on Debian, e.g. for a MariaDB JDBC connector?

Tags: debian, java, mariadb

I'm trying to install a JDBC Connector for MariaDB in the form of a JAR archive.

The instructions say to put the jar file in "an appropriate place".

Where should I put the jar file on Debian?

Comment: It's telling you to put it where the JVM can find it - in its *classpath*.

Comment: @ThomasDickey, I think I am also ask to set the classpath for this (i.e. in Libre Office under Tools | Options | LibreOffice | Advanced | Class Path...").  Is there just one class path, or are there multiple class paths, like with DOS paths?  Or do you think there is one special place that all of LibreOffice uses where I'm suppose to put it.  Sorry, but I'm really confused about this.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Usually a Java-based application has just one classpath (list of places for jar-files), because all of those jar-files are run in the same JVM (java virtual machine).  So it sounds as if you're looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**: At least on Debian an appropriate place for Java jar archives is `/usr/share/java/`

When I copied the downloaded MaridDB JDBC connector file, "mariadb-java-client-1.5.3.jar" into `/usr/share/java/`, and also set LibreOffice | Tools | Options | Advanced | LibreOffice | Class Path... | Add Archive... to this location/file, then I was able to get the JDBC connector working.

*(Note, the Mariadb connector filename is called "java-client" instead of "java-connector", like w/ MySQL "mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar")*